# Creating file duplicates of a file

Tags: java, java-io

I want to create the duplicate of a file output. For example with this code:

```
imageCapture.takeSnapshot().save(new File(path + "/FullScreen.jpg"), ImageFormat.PNG, CompressionQuality.HIGH);
```

Every time I take a new screenshot it is overriding the previous one. Instead, something like this should happen FullScreen.jpg(1), FullScreen.jpg(2) and so on..

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

define a counter like:

```
int counter = 1;
```

and then use the command like this:

```
imageCapture.takeSnapshot().save(new File(path + "/FullScreen.jpg("+ Integer.toString(counter++) + ")"), ImageFormat.PNG, CompressionQuality.HIGH);
```